# Not showing full HTML links where are letters ćčžšđ

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from the phonebook, and the problem is that it's not showing full html link. It stops before the čćžšđ letters and my question is how to include čćžšđ letters in the html link.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.imenik.hr/imenik/trazi/1/Osobe/sve' \
  '/sve/vaznost/mjesto:vi%C5%A1njan.html'
r = urlopen(url).read()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

for container in page_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'list_naslov'):


base_url = 'http://www.imenik.hr'

for link in container.find_all('a', href=True):

    print('href:',link['href'])
    request_href = base_url + link['href'].replace(' ', '%20')
    print(request_href)
```